# Could a string in the back end be identified as a control's name of the front end in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

In front end, I have 100 images - Image1, Image2 ... Image100. Now I need to modify some of their source. For example, in back end:

```
Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dir));
```

However, I need to click a button to make these 100 images'source to be the same one. The following code is incorrect but shows what I need:

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
              ("Image"+i.ToString()).Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri(dir));
            }
```

What is the correct way to write it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "correct way" would certainly be to use an ItemsControl, where the ItemsSource is bound to a collection of view model item objects with a property that holds the image path (or an ImageSource). Its ItemTemplate would contain the Image control, which has its Source property bound like `Source="{Binding ImagePath}"`. You would then just change the item property, instead of accessing UI elements in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your images in a grid you could then loop through all the controls in a grid, if its an Image (You'll know because its not null) set the source.

```
foreach(var img in grid.Children) {
    var image = img as Image;
    if(image != null) image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dir));
}
```

---

Edit --

> Thanks. But I also have another request like randomly choose 50 of
>   these 100 images and set their source to be another image - this is
>   why I think I need to indicate each of them in the back end.

You could do something like this...

```
//Get Images and add them to a list.
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
foreach(var img in grid.Children) {
    var image = img as Image;
    images.Add(image);
}

Random random = new Random();
//Loop 50 times and pick a random image to change.
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  int r = random.Next(99);
  images[r].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dir));
}
```

You'll probably also want to check if the image has already randomly been chosen or not... I'll let you figure that out on your own. It's easy enough.

Comment: Thanks. But I also have another request like randomly choose 50 of these 100 images and set their source to be another image - this is why I think I need to indicate each of them in the back end.

Comment: When I set a break point in for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) ..., it works fine. But if I run the program directly without debugging, there will be only 1-2 pictures change. Is this due to the same value generated by Random in a short time?

Comment: Yes, it is caused by the same value generated by Random. I will use Thread.Sleep() or another way to get random values. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said in my post, you'll need to keep track of which images have already been changed. Random can choose the same number twice...